# Modern page -> Modern Document library webpart

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-on-prem, document-set

**System**: SP19 on-premise;

**Page**: Modern page;

**Webpart**: Document library;

**Situation**: I want to open DocSet in the same or the new tab with all details in in (standart docset page); 
When I pressed on Docset in webpart I get this view:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Webpart are not allowed in the modern expereince in SharePoint.

If you want to add a webpart, you can just switch to the classic library experience and then write your script (that does whatever you want to do)  and add it to the webpart